# MySQL Workbench cannot forward engineer, error 1064

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

im new in database, and i have a task from my lecture to make ERD using MySQL Workbench. I made the design but when i want to forward engineer it says error, i tried to fix it all day, but i could not figure it out. Here's the picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv5K1.png)

Comment: Pls note that mariadb is **not** mysql, it is a **fork** of mysql! Mysql workbench is designed to work with mysql, not with mariadb!

Comment: Note how it is pointing at `CONSTRAINT` as the offending token.